# What is the best way to maintain backlogs [features/bugs/tasks] in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, backlog

What is the best way to maintain backlogs [features/bugs/tasks] in GitHub for a open source project? or Are there any alternatives to do the same in a better way?

**Edit:** I had asked this question because i have to maintain my code and all the requirements in GitHub only. I am now able to completely maintained my project using GitHub only.

1. For Code, I have used git repo
2. For issues, I have used the issues section. To distinguish between feature, bug, priority, story point, open, in-progress, done I am using GitHub Labels
3. For deployment steps, requirements, API documentation, and other how to documents I am using wiki.

   4. GitHub only support image attachment and does not support file attachments for this I am using google docs. Maintain the documents and provide access to company employees and maintained the link to each issues.
   5. For code review I am using pull requests.

[image: Below is the snapshot of my project.]

If you are maintaining project in GitHub and having difficulties please drop your queries. I will be very happy to assist you. Or if you have better way to do it do share with us.

Comment: What's wrong with the ‘Issues’ functionality?

Comment: Biffen, I am also using the issues with the labels mentioned by @VonC below. But checking if there is a better way to do it. You never know right ?

Comment: @VonC I am writing the answer because somebody down vote my question. I think we need to understand when I was maintaining the project first time at GitHub I did not find the way to start. Your answer help me to get start. Thanks for answering and apologies for forgotten to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main features proposes by the Issues section of a GitHub project is the labels.

See "[How we organize GitHub issues: A simple styleguide for tagging](https://robinpowered.com/blog/best-practice-system-for-organizing-and-tagging-github-issues/)"

You can see an example in [**robinpowered/swolebot**](https://github.com/robinpowered/swolebot/labels).
It should be possible to add a backlog label, for grouping issues in it.

Comment: Exactly! I am also using the Issues/milestone/labels. Just want to verify whether this is the best way to do it or not.

Comment: @BhuwanGautam I believe that is the current best practice.

Comment: @BonC thank you for your confirmation. I will continue with the same.